# How to approximate using the differential to calculate the value of trigonometric functions?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, differential

I'm working a practice problem for Calculus 2 and I can't figure out a way to proceed, I'm stuck.

The function is:
$$
h(t)=\arcsin(t^2)
$$
The requested value to calculate with the differential is:
$$
\arcsin(0.6)
$$

I understand the theory and have already done similar problems but those involved square roots, polynomial expressions and others . They were easier.

The differential for h is $dh=h'(t)·dt$, so to calculate it one would use: 
$$
h(t+∆t)=h(t)+h'(t)·∆t
$$
But I tried making $x=0 $, $x=-1$, $x=1$  and it didn't work because it resulted in an indetermination or a wrong value. I can't think of any other value to plug in the inverse sine function so the result is known or exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Set $t=1/2$ and $\Delta t=0.1$ and remember that $\sin (\frac{\pi}{6})=1/2$

Comment: Right! But in the function the variable is squared and the value changes to 1/4, how can I overcome that?

Comment: Is the task to compute $h(0.6)$ or $\arcsin(0.6)$?

Comment: It's arcsin(0.6) but in the given function the variable is squared

Comment: You are being asked to calculate $\arcsin (0.6)$. It seems to me the given $h(t)$ is irrelevant for this problem.

Comment: Maybe there's a stability or quickness of convergence issue that makes $h$ a stronger choice than just plain $\arcsin$(?)

Comment: Yeah, for me it doesn't make sense that the problem gives you a function that is squared when you can use the plain one that isn't and get the same result. Thank you all for commenting!